How to deal with lexical ambiguity with tree diagram in the framework of TG Grammar?
The example is "I saw him at the bank." The ambiguity of the sentence does not come from its structure but the different interpretations of the word "bank".
And how does TG grammar deal with lexical ambiguity in sentence analysis?

So you're specifically interested in the ambiguity between "I saw him at the edge of the river" and "I saw him at the financial institution", not the ambiguity between "I saw him while he was at the bank" and "I saw him while I was at the bank"?

Yes, exactly. Maybe "He is at the bank" is a better answer.
